# backward search in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have the list with lines like:

```
=cat-egory/packagename-version
```

so I have to split it up into 3 different variables, like

```
category = cat-egory
package_name = packagename
package_version = version
```

I have to avoid 
`=` and `/` 
chars

I am fond of perl so I used to write a regexp like:

```
(?<==)\w+.\w+
```

which would give me `cat-egory` without leading `=` character

and so on, but as far as I know `?<=` does not work in python, how must I extract the data then?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Python does have a "?<=" flag. According to the documentation, it "Matches if the current position in the string is preceded by a match for "..." that ends at the current position." Is that not what it does in perl?

Comment: Wild guess: try using `re.search` instead of `re.match`.

Comment: @ScottHunter, it returned just `None`

Comment: @Kevin, the same, see comment above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to work OK, maybe you are just missing the basic Python framework for capturing:

```
import re

text = "=cat-egory/packagename-version"
results = re.search("(?<==)\w+.\w+", text)
if results:
    print (results.group(0))
```

output:

```
cat-egory
```

Make sure to use .search instead of .match as suggested by a comment.  the .group is how you reference what you have captured instead of $1 in perl.  Nothing too fancy here :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working well. See: https://regex101.com/r/nnMRKd/2

Comment: Are you guaranteeing that Python's regex parser works identically to the one on regex101.com?

Comment: Also, please do not encourage OP who does not read docs or try code themselves.

Comment: I've tested it there too, and got positive result, but it does not work as expected in the script itself

Comment: @M.Mass: Then maybe you should have posted the script.

Answer (score 0):

You could even go one step further and use tuple unpacking:

```
import re

string = "=cat-egory/packagename-version"

rx = re.compile(r'(?<==)([^/]+)/([^-]+)-(.+)')

for match in rx.finditer(string):
    category, package_name, version = match.groups()
    print(category)
    # cat-egory
```